# Can I insert a value into another entity? TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I have the following;

```
@Entity()
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number

  @Column()
  name: string

}
```

Let's say I add a new User with

```
{name: "Kahvi", gold: "200", exp: "500"}
```

How would I go about adding gold & exp to an inventory entity within User?

Comment: I mean, I would normally just add `exp` and `gold` as columns in your entity. Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: @Bodacious Yep. I need it to remain as a reference only.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Bodacious I want to keep User and their Player Data seperate. User will contain usernames, userIDs, and such, and the Data entity will contain Gold, Exp, Level, Stats, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably create a child entity for `Inventory` with columns for `type` and `quantity`, and whatever other columns might make sense.

Example:

```
@Entity()
export class User {    
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => InventoryItem, item => item.user)
  inventory: InventoryItem[];
}

@Entity()
export class InventoryItem {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  type: string;

  @Column()
  quantity: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.inventory)
  user: User;
}
```

Then you can add items to it that look more like this:

```
{ 
  name: "Kahvi",
  inventory: [
    {
      type: "gold",
      quantity: 200
    },
    {
      type: "exp",
      quantity: 500
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow - are you saying the values aren't in the DB, or are you saying that when you load the user from the DB the inventory is blank? If the latter, TypeORM does not automatically load child entities. You have to either tell it to load the child entity (https://typeorm.io/#relations-faq/how-to-load-relations-in-entities) or make the relationship an "eager" relationship (https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations)